# Mock testing function in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocking

I have a func `A()` in class `Characters`.

I want to mock function `A` so I did this:

```
const char = new Character(); 
jest.spyOn(char, 'A').mockImplementation(async ({}) => {
     throw new Error('something'); 
})
```

When I try to run another function that uses A, for example `getChars()`. and I need to loop and run A a few times, I get to a point that I get to the **ACTUAL original** function `A`!

Why does this happen? why does this not use the mock function again?
please help!

I tried changing the implementation but nothin worked.

Comment: Have you tried mocking the prototype method? `jest.spyOn(Character.prototype, 'A')`

Comment: Can't help without seeing the `A()` method. Is it a class method or instance method or a [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties)